# Validating email To field value in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking to validate values sent to an Outlook email in VBA

I have found several examples, such as :-

http://www.geeksengine.com/article/validate-email-vba.html

Using the code from the site above, the email address `1@1.com` is returned True, or valid. However, `1@1.com; 2@1.com` is returned as invalid. Whilst this isn't a valid email address, it is a valid value for a To field in Outlook.

Is it possible to validate a value such as `1@1.com; 2@1.com` using VBA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Validating an Outlook `To` field is a hard task.

Consider the following lines:

```
a@a.com<SomeName;b@b.com 'Valid, 2 addresses, first one named SomeName
a@a<a.com 'Invalid, < needs to be escaped
a@a.com.com;;b@b.com; 'Valid, 2 addresses
a@a.com;a 'Invalid, second address is not valid
a<b@a.com 'Weirdly enough, this is valid according to outlook, mails to b@a.com 
          '(ignores part before the <)
a@a.com<b@a.com 'But this isn't valid 
                '(closing > needed in this specific case, mail address = a@a.com)
```

The only reasonable way to validate an Outlook `To` field in my opinion, is to check if Outlook thinks it's valid. Any approximation is bound to go wrong.

You can use the following code to let Outlook validate the to string, and check if it can determine a mail address for each field

```
Public Function IsToValid(ToLine As String) As Boolean
    Dim olApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
    Dim mail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set mail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Dim rp As Object 'Outlook.Recipient
    With mail
        .To = ToLine
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
        For Each rp In .Recipients
            If rp.Address & "" = "" Then
                mail.Delete
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End With
    mail.Delete
    IsToValid = True
End Function
```

Comment: Nice one, copying to my library :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Split()` function to split the string into the individual addresses, and check these in a loop with your function.

If all addresses are valid, the original string is valid.

The nice thing about it: you don't need separate cases. A single address without `;` will return a single array element from `Split()`, and the loop will simply run once.

Answer (score 2):

**To validate multiple email ids using regex use below function:**

```
Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(ByVal strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Catch

    Dim objRegExp As New RegExp
    Dim blnIsValidEmail As Boolean

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "^((\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)\s*[;]{0,1}\s*)+$"

    blnIsValidEmail = objRegExp.test(strEmailAddress)
    ValidateEmailAddress = blnIsValidEmail

    Exit Function

Catch:
    ValidateEmailAddress = False
    MsgBox "Module: " & MODULE_NAME & " - ValidateEmailAddress function" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
        & "Error#:  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Note that your answer fails both example 1 and 3 of the difficult to validate `To` lines I provided in my answer. It's a lot more strict than Outlook is.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  You are correct, I just validated with possible values provided by OP.